# 2d Array Python :list index out of range

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to Python programming and I am trying to write code to check if a DFA( Deterministic Finite Automata) has empty language or not.

I am using 2-d array to store state of the DFA.
 On executing the code I keep getting list index out of range. How can I fix this?

Below is the code

```
top=-1
count=0
n=int(input("\nEnter the no of states"))
mat=[[]]
b=[]
print("\nEnter the transition table")
for i in range(0,n):
   for j in range(0,n):
    mat.append(input())
finalState=input("\nEnter the final state:")
startState=input("\nEnter the start state:")      

for i in range(0,n):
   for j in range(0,n):
      if mat[i][j]:
        b[++top]=j
for k in range(top):
      if b[k]==finalState:
      count+=1
if count>0:
print("\nLanguage is  not empty")
else:
print("\nLanguage is empty")
```

Comment: In  b[++top]=j    I am getting list assignment index out of range

Comment: I'll edit my answer to address that problem too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you make a 2x2 table, you want mat to be [[1,2],[3,4]], but you're getting [[],1,2,3,4] right now.

Instead, try:

```
mat = []
for i in range(n):
    row = []
    for j in range(n):
        row.append(input())
    mat.append(row)
```

Also, Python does not have a "++" operator, so `b[++top]=j` is the same as `b[top] = j`. If you want to increment `top`, you have to do that on its own line before you use it to index the list.

On top of that, `b` has zero elements, so indexing it in any way will cause a crash. If you're trying to increase the size of `b` by adding new items to it, use `append`. Then you don't need a `top` variable at all.

```
b.append(j)
```

Comment: Really sorry for late reply, and thanks for helping me